# Recommendation for a physics history/non-fiction book

Tags: resource-recommendations, history

I know that there are a lot theses being published on lives of physicists. Is there a history/non-fiction book that tracks the development of a problem chronologically? Like pieces of a puzzle. 
I would like it to be mathematical and trying to get into the heads of people trying to solve that problem.

Something like  a case study.

Comment: Can i know why the downvote?

Comment: Yes. This isn't a constructive question and book questions aren't accepted any more. Use search. You may be interested in http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18632/

Comment: ok.  
Is there a part of SE where book questions be acceptable?

Comment: @BrandonEnright I think it is enough if the question gets closed (BTW I still [disagree](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4202/2751) with the corresponding relatively recent change of policies). Asking about a book is not that a terrible sin like posting spam or really bad stuff that it needs to be downvoted too ... So I countervoted the downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is hardly a book covering all physics, but for particular subjects there is some. For example:
*Jammer: The Conceptual Development of Quantum Mechanics.*
*Whittaker: A History of The Theories of Aether and Electricity.*

Comment: Cool! Thanks. these do seem to fit the bill.  
I didn't ask for one encompassing all of physics, but specific problems, e.g Quasiparticles (how they appear in different contexts all over the place - and how one is different from the other), for light reading - but aware of the technical details all the same.

Comment: Such books become more rare for the areas developed in the mid- and second half of 20th century. Though I know another couple: 1) _The Rise of the Standart Model_ 2) _Goenner: On the History of Unified Field Theories_ (an article).
About quasiparticles, I haven't met anything of such kind.